# Azure DevOps - CSV Import - Text in Repro Steps does not keep structure

Tags: azure-devops, csv-import

I am importing a bug through a csv file but azure devops gets and display the text in the Repro Steps fields without spaces, order, etc. as are being written/ provided in the csv.

I tried to import the same info as an Issue Work Item and the text in the Description field was imported without structure as well.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

No structure in imported text (numbers, lists, spaces, etc.)

Comment: Hi, that's the only way? That is what I would like to avoid. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, what do you want to avoid? The HTML formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Import or update rich-text fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#import-or-update-rich-text-fields),

> You can update or import rich-text fields such as the Description or Acceptance Criteria fields. Rich-text fields are HTML formatted fields.

I tested the following csv file and it works.

```
ID,Work Item Type,Title,State,Description,Repro Steps
,"Bug","bug","New",,"<ol><li><strike>step1 </strike> </li><li><i>step2</i> </li><li><b>step3</b> </li> </ol><b><h1><ul><li><b>1</b> </li> </ul> </h1><ul><li><b>2</b> </li><li><b>3</b> </li> </ul></b>"
,"Issue","issue","Active","<div><ol><li><span style=""color:rgb(243, 144, 29);"">first</span> </li><li><span style=""background-color:rgb(0, 255, 0);"">second</span> </li> </ol> </div>",
,"Issue","Hello World Web Site - 8","Active","<p><strong>&nbsp;You can include bold text</strong></p><p><em>&nbsp;And italic text</em></p><p><u>&nbsp;Underline text</u></p>"
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

If it doesn't work in your side, you can share your CSV sample file for further check.